# Find the score of each question in a test given arrays that represents the ones that the person got right

Tags: python, dataframe, sorting

1st question here, so I may be not doing it the better way

I'm here stuck with a problem: **discover the scores of the questions in a test**.

Actually I don't really need to know the score (it would be great but more complicated), only sort the questions from the easier to the more difficult. The easier would get you more points, and difficult ones less points, similar to the SAT.

What I have are arrays with the questions that a person got right. Example:

```
Questions .... Total score

...
[ 9, 28, 43]   =   371.1
[10, 17, 43]   =   371.0
[13, 37, 42]   =   371.0
[ 9, 31, 37]   =   370.9
[ 5, 16, 39]   =   370.9
[ 9, 33, 42]   =   370.6
[ 9, 16, 42]   =   370.5
[16, 27, 37]   =   370.5
...
```

The data are in a pandas dataframe.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you checked [`sort_values()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) method

Comment: It's no the case for `sort_values()` because I want to sort individually. So, I kown that the set [ 9, 28, 43] is easier than [10, 17, 43], but what I want to know is if **9** is easier than **10** or **17**